# How to implement Continuous Integration with Puppet and multiple services

Tags: git, continuous-integration, puppet

We're trying to implement a Continuous Integration pipeline in our environment. We have a lot of different services, each with its own Git repository. Deployment is done via Puppet, using an external node classifier that determines what classes to deploy to each host type. And the Puppet files are sitting in their own Git repo, as depicted here:

[image: Puppet and Git]

Only, it's not just 3 services, it's more like 100. So the Puppet project is this monstrous monolith of multiple manifests, and of course it's in its own independent Git repo.

Now, along comes lil' ol' me, tasked with setting up a pattern for CI, so that when someone requests to merge a branch from, say, Service A, into master, we should be able to kick off a CI build that will spin up a virtual environment, deploy Service A to some VMs, and ensure that the new branch passes all automated tests. Of course, the problem is that to deploy a new build of Service A, I not only have to build it, but I also have to update the Puppet manifest to refer to the new build version...and the Puppet files are sitting in a completely independent repo, not on my branch. So I don't have any easy way to tell the Puppet Master that for *this* branch, we need to use the CI build, not the master version.

I can't be the first person ever to want to set up CI for an environment like this, but I've searched the web for solutions and come up empty. Perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.

Can anyone suggest a suitable design pattern that will enable me to implement CI for all my service repos?

*(Please pardon the cross-posting. I originally posted this on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/1091358/23577), but it got almost no attention there, even with a bounty. Maybe this is more of a programming question than a SysEng question.)*

Comment: I see two solution, the big one, break your monolith and bring a maximum into the service repo, this can be the hard way, but the best imho.
Other solution add somevariable into your monolith, from service A you call your big monolith part with the branch name, then the monolith hydrate a template for the manifest according to the parameter

Comment: @Ôrel sounds like a possibility, can you put more flesh on that answer please?

Comment: The part to rework I think is this one `using an external node classifier that determines what classes to deploy to each host type`. Hard to give more advice without knowing more your current deployment process